# Is s3fuse a good alternative to AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I need to provide an alternative solution for AWS EFS as the service is not available in our region.  I can provide performance requirements if that determines the recommended solution although I've read the following page and s3fuse is apparently a possible solution.

Has anyone used this in production and with what limitations have you experienced?

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5g786x/any_alternative_solutions_of_aws_efs/

The solution would need to support 
around 1000 new documents/ minute with the document size 4-8mb

Comment: As I read that page, almost everyone who has tried s3fuse has regretted it. And yes, use case and performance requirements are necessary to have any chance at a good answer.

Comment: I've added the performance demands to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use s3fuse as a solution for shared file system for use case with multiple reads and infrequent writes. AWS has a private link between vpc to s3. So you can access the object store within a low latency network instead of accessing it via an external internet gateway.

There are some [limitations](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse#limitations) that are not addressed yet..

[performance benchmarks](https://github.com/kahing/goofys#benchmark) for reference..

If you need a reliable shared storage file system, you can set up [NFS cluster](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_administration/ch-startup-haaa) with high availability. It can setup with minimum 2 nodes.

Comment: Is s3fuse still a valid suggestion for the throughput?

Comment: We cannot expect a maximum throughput as same as traditional shared file system, it is not suitable for accessing large amount of smaller files. But it works well with concurrent reading of larger files in a low latency network. AWS EMR uses S3 as a storage backend for HDFS and EMR filesystem.

Comment: When you say "accessing large amount of smaller files" are you saying a 1000 new documents every minute is large?

Comment: Yes, It has a significant performance impact if it continues to grow at the same rate.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to create a performance test to see if I can see the degradation as the files increase.